# How will I know if my closed question will ever be re-opened?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, closed-questions

I've recently had a question on Stack Overflow be closed because it needs "details or clarity", personally, I disagree with this.

The question in question can be found here:
[How can I force an old-style Alt-Tab dialog programatically in Windows 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62247560/how-can-i-force-an-old-style-alt-tab-dialog-programatically-in-windows-10)

Since my question has been closed I have clarified my post, and added a minimum reproducible example. This was over 24 hours ago, and I have not seen my post be re-opened, or heard any more information.

How will I know if my question will ever be re-opened? More importantly, how will I know if my edits have sufficiently addressed "details or clarity" without personal feedback from the voters who closed it in the first place?

Comment: In the [post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62247560/timeline), I'm seeing a [reopen review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/26370410) as a mod. Not sure if you can though.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I think it only appears in the public timeline if the review is complete. I certainly can't find that review by means of the timeline. Not sure if an OP can but I doubt it. For reference my view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJhJs.png

Comment: Personal feedback from the voters who closed it doesn't scale to a site the size of Stack Overflow. You can find out the level of detail expected by reading [ask] and [the FAQs around asking questions here on Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions+faq).

Comment: Also related to voting feedback: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/6296561

Comment: "How will I know if my closed question will ever be re-opened?" Nobody knows what the future may bring but it looks like we could be more transparent about the review process here. For example by printing stats about the current status of re-open review process. "Your question is under re-opening review." "Your change was reviewed and the decision was that ..."

Comment: Side note: your resistance to *edit the question* with things you tried and did not work is ... not really appreciated. I don't get why you so against adding that information into the question. If you can explain that it may be good meta question on how to prevent that with other users to properly encourage them to edit they questions..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I believe my addition of things that I tried was confusing people, which I beleived caused people to vote the question to be closed, because they were confused.

Answer (score 3):

A minimum reproducible example mostly makes sense when you have a bug in existing code and need help to track it down. In this case, you are rather asking how to achieve something - possibly complex - with the use of Windows API calls. So the example didn't add that much, but at least it gives the context that you wish to do this with C# .NET.

It's not an ideal question, because either the answer is complex and therefore the question would be too broad ("how do I do my whole project" questions are too broad). Or the answer is trivial - it can be done by a simple API call. Such questions are not explicitly off-topic, but often frowned upon if someone reads them as "look this up for me" or "read the manual for me".

However, since you posted the original question, which wasn't great for the above mentioned reasons, you have done lots of research and added details, so I think it's a quite sensible question now. The post *was* re-opened, by a moderator none the less, but then closed again as unclear, not sure why. You can view the edit history here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62247560/revisions.

I've cast another re-open vote, it's sitting at 2 currently. You should get a notification when it gets re-opened by reviewer consensus (3 votes).

---

(As for the question itself, it would seem that you can achieve what you want by writing to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AltTabSettings
```

And changing the DWORD value from 0 to 1. This is quite trivial to do at least in raw Windows API with C programming. I'm sure it's possible to do so in C# too, so maybe just ask how to write to the above register key in C#?)

Comment: "I don't think you get any notification when it gets re-opened, sadly." - actually, OP and anyone following will. I got a notification when my meta post got reopened anyway, so I assume that applies to main as well.

Comment: Changing the registry requires a restart of the explorer.exe process, and would affect any calls to Alt+Tab, whereas the OP wants it to occur only for their own. This was dicussed in the comments (which should have been folded into the question).

Comment: @Zoe Ok I'll take your word for it and edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't think my issue is anywhere in the manual or look-up-able unfortunately, I believe the program I used as an example must be using some undocumented Windows API feature

Comment: @Cherona Hmm ok well apparently the "alt tab window" is a window, so it should be possible to change its behavior somehow. This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30806029/get-all-windows-from-alttab-excluding-metro-windows-windows-8-8-1.